# Removing duplicate rows in .tsv while keeping some of the data (bash, perl)

Tags: bash, perl, duplicates

I have a number of large .tsv files such as the following:

```
rownbr     pos      pvalue   percentage    samplename
1      chr1_12000    0.05       5.6            S1
1      chr1_12500    0.04       15.9           S1
3      chr1_12570    0.9        45.3           S2
2      chr1_12500    0.03       13.8           S3
```

I would like to remove duplicate rows based on the **pos** column, while still keeping the values of both rows for columns **3** and **5** so that the output could look something like this:

```
rownbr     pos      pvalue   percentage    samplename
1      chr1_12000    0.05       5.6            S1
1      chr1_12500    0.04,0.03  15.9           S1,S3
3      chr1_12570    0.9        45.3           S2
```

My idea was to first sort the .tsv files using the shell *sort* function:

```
sort -k 2,2 *.tsv
```

And then write a script that would compare each line to the following line.
If the string in the **pos** column is the same for both lines, then it would concatenate the values of column 3 and 5 in **row n+1** to the ones in **row n**.
However I have no idea how to do this.

I am familiar with awk/sed/grep/bash but also have some (limited) perl basics.

Thanks for your help !

Comment: In the expected output: Why is the percentage column for pos=12500 `15.9` and not `13.8` ? Similarly, why is the `rownbr` column `1` and not `2`.  Can there be more that 2 duplicates lines for a given `pos`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an example of how you could approach it in Perl:

```
use feature qw(say);
use strict;
use warnings;

my $fn = 'file1.tsv';
open ( my $fh, '<', $fn ) or die "Could not open file '$fn': $!";
my $header = <$fh>;
my @pos;
my %info;
while( my $line = <$fh> ) {
    chomp $line;
    my ($nbr, $pos, $pvalue, $percentage, $samplename) = split /\t/, $line;
    if ( !exists $info{$pos} ) {
        $info{$pos} = {
            nbr        => $nbr,
            pvalue     => [$pvalue],
            percentage => $percentage,
            samplename => [$samplename],
        };
        push @pos, $pos;
    }
    else {
        push @{$info{$pos}{pvalue}}, $pvalue; 
        push @{$info{$pos}{samplename}}, $samplename; 
    }
}    
close $fh;

print $header;
for my $pos (@pos) {
    my $data = $info{$pos};
    say join "\t", $data->{nbr}, $pos,
      (join ",", @{$data->{pvalue}}), $data->{percentage},
      (join ",", @{$data->{samplename}});
}
```

**Output**:

```
rownbr     pos      pvalue   percentage    samplename
1   chr1_12000  0.05    5.6 S1
1   chr1_12500  0.04,0.03   15.9    S1,S3
3   chr1_12570  0.9 45.3    S2
```

Comment: This works perfectly, thanks @HåkonHægland ! 
To answer your questions above, I chose to keep only the first occurence of the percentage numbers for the desired output. The main point of this was to show that I didn't want to keep values from all columns, but that's it. I should have made it more clear.
And yes there can be more than 2 duplicate lines for a given pos, but your code works no matter how many duplicates, so it is great !

Answer (score 1):

file "myscript":

```
#! /usr/bin/env bash

file="$1"

result="$(tr -s '\t' < "${file}"  | tail -n +2 |
        awk -F'\t' -v OFS='\t' '

        $0 == "" {
            next
        }

        # MAIN 
        {
            if (col3[$2] == "") {
                col1[$2] = $1
                col3[$2] = $3
                col4[$2] = $4   
                col5[$2] = $5
            } else {
                col3[$2] = col3[$2]","$3
                col5[$2] = col5[$2]","$5
            }
        }

        END {

            for (pos in col1) {
                print col1[pos], pos, col3[pos], col4[pos], col5[pos]
            }
        }
        ' | sort -k 2,2 )"

first_line="$(head -n 1 "${file}")"
echo "${first_line}"
echo "${result}"
```

Run it as:

```
bash myscript <your tsv file>
```

It will write result to stdout.

Comment: Thanks @Mihir !
This works well on the example dataframe that I provided.
I will still keep Hakon's perl answer as main answer as I find it easier to adapt to more complicated dataframes.

Answer (score 1):

Using a combination of [GNU `datamash`](https://www.gnu.org/software/datamash/) and `awk` to get just the desired columns:

```
$ datamash --header-in -sf -g2 collapse 3,5 < input.tsv | \
  awk 'BEGIN { FS=OFS="\t"; print "rownbr\tpos\tpvalue\tpercentage\tsamplename" }
       { print $1, $2, $6, $4, $7 }'
rownbr  pos pvalue  percentage  samplename
1   chr1_12000  0.05    5.6 S1
1   chr1_12500  0.04,0.03   15.9    S1,S3
3   chr1_12570  0.9 45.3    S2
```

---

Ignore the header line in the file (`--header-in`), group records on the second column (`-g2`), sort based on that column (`-s`), output the full line (-`f`) in addition to the given operations, and for the 3rd and 5th columns, collapse all rows of the group into a single CSV entry. Tnen use `awk` to put the desired columns in the right order.

Comment: Hi @Shawn, thanks for your answer.
The computer cluster where I store my data doesn't have the GNU datamash installed and as I am not authorized to install any packages there, the perl answer from HåkonHægland works better for me in the short run.
However, this looks interesting and quite straightforward. I have never used GNU commands but might give them a look in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Perl is perfect tool for this task.

> save header of the data for future output.
>
> extract `pos` field to be used as hash key
>
> save a line into a hash if we not seen this `pos` before, otherwise
>   merge value and name into the line.
>
> Once all lines processed output result (in this case I use 'format' and write)

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

my(@pos,%seen,%lines);
my $header = <DATA>;                            # obtain header

chomp $header;

while(<DATA>) {
    next if /^\s*$/;                            # skip empty lines

    chomp;

    my $key = (split '\s+')[1];                 # extract 'pos' to use as $key

    if( $seen{$key} ) {
        my($value,$name) = (split '\s+')[2,4];  # extract value and name
        $lines{$key} =~ s/(\d\s+\S+\s+\S+)/$1,$value/;  # merge value
        $lines{$key} =~ s/$/,$name/;            # merge name
    } else {
        push @pos, $key;                        # preserve order
        $lines{$key} = $_;                      # store lines in a hash
        $seen{$key} = 1;
    }
}


say $header;                                    # output header

my @data;

for (@pos) {                                    # use stored hash 'indexes'
    @data = split '\s+',$lines{$_};             # split into fields
    write;                                      # output
}

# format STDOUT_HEADER = 
# rownbr     pos      pvalue   percentage    samplename
# .

format STDOUT = 
@<<<<< @<<<<<<<<<    @<<<<<<<<  @<<<<<         @<<<<<<<<<<<<
$data[0],$data[1],$data[2],$data[3],$data[4]
.

__DATA__
rownbr     pos      pvalue   percentage    samplename
1      chr1_12000    0.05       5.6            S1
1      chr1_12500    0.04       15.9           S1
3      chr1_12570    0.9        45.3           S2
2      chr1_12500    0.03       13.8           S3
```

Output

```
rownbr     pos      pvalue   percentage    samplename
1      chr1_12000    0.05       5.6            S1
1      chr1_12500    0.04,0.03  15.9           S1,S3
3      chr1_12570    0.9        45.3           S2
```